# Oracle Discoverer: FIRST_VALUE not working in CASE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, business-intelligence

First, allow me to preface by saying that I am using Oracle's BI Tool called "Discoverer" and do not have access to direct SELECT querying. I am writing this as a calculation. I do not have access to the admin version and cannot edit the current functionality. However, suggestions of the sort are still welcome.

I have scoured the internet and can’t figure this one out. In discoverer, I have a function that is pulling the date of 6/11/2015 for multiple records (exactly what I want), as shown below:

```
FIRST_VALUE(Sla Due Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Vw Research Sla.Loan Id  ORDER BY  Sla Type )
```

However, when I plug this function into a CASE WHEN THEN ELSE function, it will not return a value (it returns null instead of FIRST_VALUE value), as shown below:

```
CASE WHEN Contract Type IN ('Recon Contract') AND State IN ('GA') 
THEN TRUNC(Static OOC Date)-35 

WHEN Contract Type IN ('Recon Contract') 
THEN TRUNC(Static OOC Date) 

WHEN Contract Type IN ('Assignment Contract') 
THEN FIRST_VALUE(Sla Due Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Vw Research Sla.Loan Id ORDER BY  Sla Type )

ELSE TRUNC(Sla Due Date) END
```

I tried to replace the FIRST_VALUE within the CASE statement with the calculation name instead of using the direct analytical function and it still gave a null value

```
CASE WHEN Contract Type IN ('Recon Contract') AND State IN ('GA') THEN TRUNC(Static NTC OOC Date)-35 WHEN Contract Type IN ('Recon Contract') THEN TRUNC(Static NTC OOC Date) WHEN Contract Type IN ('Assignment Contract') THEN **mSLA** ELSE TRUNC(Sla Due Date) END
```

**Update**: I spoke with one of my companies DBAs and they plugged the code from the SQL Inspector into Dell's TOAD for Oracle and it output the data fine. It seems to be an issue only associated with how Discoverer compiles the Analytical Function within the CASE statement. Any suggestions on this or anyone else have a similar problem?

Comment: Update: I spoke with one of my companies DBAs and they plugged the code from the SQL Inspector into Dell's TOAD for Oracle and it output the data fine. It seems to be an issue only associated with how Discoverer compiles the Analytical Function within the CASE statement. Any suggestions on this or anyone else have a similar problem?

Comment: While I'm afraid I don't have an answer for you, I'd just like to suggest that you edit your question to include the note in your comment. Comments are considered potentially temporary here on SO, and it's best to edit your question to include all the relevant information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The FIRST_VALUE calculation should be added in Discoverer Administrator to the Folder.  The issue with Discoverer is that it is unable to properly determine the data type from FIRST_VALUE which the CASE statement requires.

10+ years experience in Oracle Discoverer.